# How to eliminate lines that are added when "join multiple line" plugin is used?

Tags: qgis, line

I'm new in QGIS. I have three road shapes. If I merge them, I cannot use "network analysis" (shortest path) because the merged lines are not continuous. I tried to use "Join Multiple Lines" and, actually, it worked. However, when I used it, some lines were added and I don't how to eliminate them.